# DDD, NHibernate, and Project Structure / Naming

Tags: .net, nhibernate, naming-conventions, domain-driven-design, projects-and-solutions

What do you recommend as the proper project structure for a WebForms solution that is utilizing NHibernate and trying to bring in some DDD concepts?

Assuming the root namespace and solution name is Sample

- Sample.Domain - contains my domain objects and my mapping files
- Sample.Repositories - contains my repositories and nhibernate connection config file
- Sample.Business - contains my business logic
- Sample.Web - the actual WebForms project - all Presentation

What am I forgetting? Is there a more standard way to name these?
Any great blog posts on the topic?

Comment: Should have included the test projects. thx

Comment: Was going to have a look at what CodeCampServer does. Can't check out the source code. Weird repository has relocated error. Anybody else able to check it out? details: http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/checkout

Comment: Your business logic should be in domain.

Comment: I guess in a DDD sense I meant services. I would have some business logic related to Entities in the Domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few parts missing seem to be a central location for services needed throughout the solution and test projects. I usually have something like this:

- Sample.Core - services and code that need to be used across the application
- Sample.Data - domain classes and repository interfaces
- Sample.Data.NHibernate - mapping files, fluent config, etc. and repository implementations, basically anything data mapping layer specific
- Sample.Services - service implementations and interfaces
- Sample.Web - web application

I have a matching tree of test projects:

- Tests\Sample.Core.Tests
- Tests\Sample.Data.NHibernate.Tests
- etc...

Of course, the tree will get more complex depending on the project. As for discussions, check out the [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). You can also check out the sample projects on [Domain-Driven Design](http://www.domaindrivendesign.org/) and see what you can take from those.

Answer (score 2):

I have found everyone has their own preferences for naming, I prefer:

- Sample.Domain - domain objects, mapping files
- Sample.Services - business logic and services (and repositories, although I could see separating these out)
- Sample.Web - Web Stuff.
- Sample.Migrations - Data migrations.

Ben Scheirman also recently posted about this: [Exporting Visual Studio Solutions with Solution Factory](http://benscheirman.com/2009/04/exporting-visual-studio-solutions-with-solutionfactory).

He uses a different structure but also includes a great way to standardize your template.

Answer (score 2):

I keep it simple and lean towards segregating by namespace rather than by project, especially at the beginning. I usually start with three projects in the solution:

- Sample - contains namespaces Sample.Model, Sample.Model.Mappings, and Sample.Services.
- Sample.Tests - contains unit tests is structured the same as Sample.
- Sample.Web - UI

Comment: What is the Sample.Model.Mappings for?

Comment: The Fluent NHibernate mapping classes.

Comment: Gotcha. Not using that yet. Thanks.

Comment: I follow the same approach. It's easy to get bogged down in how to structure your project. I prefer to wait until there is a genuine requirement/benefit to splitting out further.

Answer (score 1):

You can see how it is done in [s#arp architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture). Its a very solid architectural framework

Comment: As of 2019, this domain appears to have expired. It now points to a domain parking page.